# .net based oData service without entity framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a oData service using .net core. I will be connecting to SQL Cubes (SSAS). Because of this reason I cannot use Entity Framework. All the examples for creating oData service I have seen so far are using Entity Framework.

My plan is to connect to connect to cube using ADOMD.net. When call is made to endpoint, execute a DAX query, get result set. Then oData on its apply the filters on top of resultset.

This does not seem like a good design, because I am fetching huge result-set and then applying filters. Does it makes sense to create oData service without using entity framework ? What alternatives do I have ? Ideally when filters are applied, I want to pass those filters to database and only fetch minimum records.

Comment: Aaccess database with ADO.NET?

Comment: You should think about using IQuerable on accessing any database that you want to use

Comment: @DilshodK: Can you please share more details. How that will help ?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng; when I access DB using ADO.NET, how my query would look ? lets say user via oData applied a filter Region='North America', My understanding is I will `select * from tablename` query and then let oData to filter the data. Does it makes sense ?